# Finding ^@ character in unix?

Tags: c++, regex, unix, hex, character

I'm writing a C++ program where I'm reading file info that contains ^@ between a lot of words. What is this character? I'm guessing it's some expression of a hex value but which one? And what would be the regular expression to match it? Sorry if this is a duplicate, I tried searching on this but no search engine accepts these characters.

I'm new to regular expressions so I have no idea what I'm doing. Would it be something like this?

```
^.*\^@*.*$
```

Comment: The ^@ is a null char ( 0 cero), so you might be looking at a MultiByte char file. Where did it come from?. There are single byte (8 bits) char AnsiChar or multibyte char (16 bits) where the first byte is 0 when the char can be represented as a byte (8 bits).

Answer (score 6):

`^@` is a representation of the null byte (character code 00). In a regular expression, it is typically denoted as `\0` or `\x00`.

**Background details:**

`^@` is the character that you get by holding down <kbd>Control</kbd> while typing <kbd>@</kbd>. Traditionally, holding down Control modifies a character code by clearing the upper three bits (putting the character into the 0x00–0x1F range); thus, <kbd>G</kbd> (0x47) turns into character BEL (0x07), and `@` (0x40) turns into NUL (0x00).